# Are resources lost during a clan war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

During a clan war, do resources lost during a defense deduct from my actual resources?

As a corollary, now that war bases are separate from regular bases, does it make sense to build an extremely resource lossy war base as it doesn't cost me anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, all your resources are safe during clan wars. This is because clan wars are fought in the "war zone", away from your normal village.

From the [wiki:](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars_FAQ#What_happens_to_my_village_during_a_clan_war.3F_Does_my_village_go_to_war_or_is_it_safe.3F)

> Your village’s resources, trophies and shield are never at risk during a clan war.

Comment: hi, you might want to answer this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198567/what-are-the-most-effective-attack-compositions-to-focus-on-general